# Load a single lodash methods for smaller builds with browserify/rollup/webpack

Tags: webpack, browserify, lodash, rollup

From https://lodash.com/:

```
// Load a single method for smaller builds with browserify/rollup/webpack.
var chunk = require('lodash/chunk');
var extend = require('lodash/fp/extend');
```

This works well with most of the methods: `each`, `map`, `isArray`, etc. The one method I connot get working is `lodash/chain`.

The current code where I import the whole lodash library goes something like this:

```
_.chain(items)
  .filter(...)
  .groupBy(...)
  .map(...)
  .concat(...)
  .value();
```

What would be the proper way of creating a proper chainable object that does not contain all methods included in the lodash build? The `chain` method creates a lodash wrapper object and returns it. I could create my own chain method like this

```
var lodash = require('lodash/wrapperLodash');
var filter = require('lodash/filter');
var map = require('lodash/map');

function chain(value) {
  var result = lodash(value);
  result.__chain__ = true;
  result.filter = filter
  result.map = map;
  return result;
}

module.exports = chain;
```

Now the call to `chain` will be able to execute `filter` and `map`. Unfortunately, the result from `chain().filter` will not have the methods I have attached in the original chain. What is the proper way of creating a custom chainable lodash object?

Comment: Found it. Started with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash. Then after using the plugin I got: Module build failed: Error: filename.js: lodash chaining syntax is not supported by babel-plugin-lodash.
Consider substituting the chaining syntax with _.flow and _.flowRight composition patterns.
See https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba. The last link has a very good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There are different solutions to this, although not all of them keep the chain capabilities.

**Lodash custom build (keeps chain)**

Use https://lodash.com/custom-builds with your custom methods. It will generate a lodash build with the methods you need. The problem I have found in the past with this solution is that the amount of size of the build is quite high even though importing a few methods, as it needs the whole lodash function that wraps your data around it to be able to use the chain.

**Import only the functions you need (No chain)**

Most of the lodash functions are available as standalone packages in npm ([example pick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick)), so you can import them individually. You will not have chain with this solution, though.

**Import functions from lodash src (No chain)**

Another solution is to import specific functions from your complete lodash module, so any bundler will only take that function with it's dependencies instead of the whole lodash, like:

```
var pick = require('lodash/pick');
```

**Advice: Don't use chain**

Although you asked specifically having the chain, I would like to discourage you from using it, as it is a bad functional programming practice. Check [this blog article](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.o7ycrqgko) (as you mentioned in your first comment) for a very thorough explanation on why is better not to use chain, and how to move away from it.